# Using the methods of scipy's rv_continuous when creating a cutom continuous distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to calculate `E[f(x)]` for some pdf that I generate/estimated from data.

It says in the documentation:

> Subclassing
>
> New random variables can be defined by subclassing rv_continuous class
>   and re-defining at least the _pdf or the _cdf method (normalized to
>   location 0 and scale 1) which will be given clean arguments (in
>   between a and b) and passing the argument check method.
>
> If positive argument checking is not correct for your RV then you will
>   also need to re-define the _argcheck method.

So I subclassed and defined _pdf but whenever I try call:

`print my_continuous_rv.expect(lambda x: x)`

scipy yells at me:

```
AttributeError: 'your_continuous_rv' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Which makes sense because I guess its trying to figure out the lower bound of the integral because it also print in the error:

```
lb = loc + self.a * scale
```

I tried defining the attribute self.a and self.b as (which I believe are the limits/interval of where the rv is defined):

```
self.a = float("-inf")
self.b = float("inf")
```

However, when I do that then it complains and says:

```
if N > self.numargs:
AttributeError: 'your_continuous_rv' object has no attribute 'numargs'
```

I was not really sure what numargs was suppose to be but after checking scipy's code on github it looks there is this line of code:

```
if not hasattr(self, 'numargs'):
    # allows more general subclassing with *args
    self.numargs = len(shapes)
```

Which I assume is the shape of the random variable my function was suppose to take.

Currently I am only doing a very simple random variable with a single float as a possible value for it. So I decided to hard code numargs to be 1. But that just lead down the road to more yelling from scipy's part.

Thus, what it boils down is that I think from the documentation its not clear to me what I have to do when I subclass it, because I did what they said, to overwrite _pdf but after doing that it asks me for self.a, which I hardcoded and then it asks me for numargs, and at this point I think I am concluding I don't really know how they want me to subclass, rv_continuous. Does some one know? I have can generate the pdf I want from the data I want to fit and then just be able to get expected values and things like that from the pdf, what else do I have to initialize in rv_continous so that it actually works?

Comment: You need to create an instance of your class

Answer (score 4):

For historical reasons, scipy distributions are *instances*, so that you need to have an instance of your subclass. For example:

```
>>> class MyRV(stats.rv_continuous):
...    def _pdf(self, x, k):
...      return k * np.exp(-k*x)
>>> my_rv = MyRV(name='exp', a=0.)     # instantiation
```

Notice the need to specify the limits of the support: default values are `a=-inf` and `b=inf`.

```
>>> my_rv.a, my_rv.b
(0.0, inf)
>>> my_rv.numargs        # gets figured out automagically
1
```

Once you've specified, say, `_pdf`, you have a working distribution instance:

```
>>> my_rv.cdf(4, k=3)
0.99999385578764677
>>> my_rv.rvs(k=3, size=4)
array([ 0.37696127,  1.10192779,  0.02632473,  0.25516446])
>>> my_rv.expect(lambda x: 1, args=(2,))    # k=2 here
0.9999999999999999
```

Answer (score 1):

SciPy's [rv_histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_histogram.html) method allows you to provide data and it provides the pdf, cdf and random generation methods.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be, you have specified a constructor with `__init__`, but did not call the base class constructor of `rv_continuous`.

If you take the example from the documentation and add a constructor like this

```
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
class gaussian_gen(rv_continuous):
    "Gaussian distribution"
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        pass
        #rv_continuous.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return np.exp(-x**2 / 2.) / np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi)

gaussian = gaussian_gen(name='gaussian')
print(gaussian.pdf(3))
```

the call to `pdf` will fail. If you comment out the call to `rv_continous.__init__`, it'll work, because then the base class constructor will add all necessary fields to the instance.