# sloped uniform distribution python

Tags: python, numpy, distribution, uniform

I would like to acquire values from a uniform distribution that is sloped instead of a standard uniform distribution which is drawing out values from a straight flat line of slope = 0. To be more specific, I'd like to get values from the function of the slope distribution, FIGURE 2 BELOW. I do know that for the first one, I could use numpy.random.uniform(initial,final). How can I do this for a sloped distribution? I know that multiplying a 'slope' or scaling factor to the values from the numpy.random.uniform does not mathematically mean that values are being drawn out from a sloped distribution. I do realize this might have something to do with changing the way each drawn out value is weighted.  source: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3662.htm
Please help! [image: standard uniform distribution plot]

[image]

Comment: You are misinterpreting these graphs. These are both of the same uniform distribution. The latter graph is just the *cumulative* distribution function of the uniform distribution, which is the integral of the probability distribution function.

Comment: @RobertKern is correct. There is no such thing as a sloped uniform distribution. There are triangular distributions (which immerrr has given an answer for) and trapezoidal distributions, is one of those what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) for this problem.

Let's look at a simple slope distribution that will generate [0;1] numbers s.t. `f(0) = 0` and `f(1) = 2`, `2` comes from normalization of `F(x)`, i.e. `F(1) = P(x <= 1) = 1` by definition of probability.

[image: maths]

According to the inverse transform sampling method, to get a random variable with necessary distribution you need to plug in a uniformly distributed random variable instead of Y into the last equation.  Let's check that:

```
In [61]: y = np.random.rand(10000)

In [62]: x = np.sqrt(y)

In [63]: plt.hist(x, bins=100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create your own pdf with [`stats.rv_continuous`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854332/using-the-methods-of-scipys-rv-continuous-when-creating-a-cutom-continuous-dist)'s a SO answer that could help you.

Some code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats

class linear(scipy.stats.rv_continuous):
    def _cdf(self, x):
        return x**2

distrib = linear(a=0, b=1.0)
d = distrib.rvs(size=10000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hist(d, normed=True, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.2, bins=100)
plt.show()
```

A histogram of random samples of the distribution:

[image]

Comment: I don't thin this works, Im getting the following: >>> print your_random_values
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

Comment: I check it out later and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, I quoted the discrete version, you have look at `stats.rv_continuous`.

Comment: After reading your question again, I realised that you're quoting the pdf and cdf of a uniform distribution. The above is not a uniform distribution. I'm not entirely sure this is what you're after...